# Moving an open file to a different device

Tags: files, rename, open-files

I have an application running that is generating a large (~200GB) output file, and takes about 35 hours to run (currently I'm about 12 hours in). The application just opens the file once then keeps it open as it is writing until it is complete; the application also does a lot of random access writes to the file (i.e. not sequential writes).

Right now the file is being saved to my local hard drive but I just decided that when it's done, I'm going to move it to a different device instead (a network drive, NTFS mounted via SMB).

To save time instead of moving the file later, is there some way I can suspend the program and somehow move the current partially complete file to the other device, do some tricks, and resume the program so it is now using the new location?

I'm pretty much positive that the answer is no but I thought I'd ask, sometimes there are surprising tricks out there...

Comment: Is the remote drive mounted using NFS?

Comment: duplicate of [Is it possible to move an open file between filesystems without "breaking" the open file descriptors to it](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-move-an-open-file-between-filesystems-without-breaking-the-open-file-descriptors-to-it-e-g-to-allow-an-in-use-external-drive-to-be-removed-safely-by-caching-the-relevant-file-locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting another solution, since file is being written randomly, breaks my `tail` idea.  Thinking `rsync` might be promising here, since the `rsync` can operate using a delta transfer algorithm, saving transfer time by only sending the changed parts of a file.  If you run `rsync` on two local files, it will default to `--whole-file` mode, which is not what you want.

Suggesting

```
rsync -av --inplace --no-whole-file /your/local/file.dat /your/remote/file.dat
```

... or maybe (if the CIFS mount doesn't agree with delta transfer) use pure `rsync`:

```
rsync -av --inplace --no-whole-file /your/local/file.dat remoteserver:/your/directory/file.dat
```

So you would run this multiple times while your 200 GB file is filling up.  Each time you run it, it updates the remote file incrementally.  This should even work when the source file is being updated randomly.  Maybe you could run this every 15 minutes.  Then when your pid finishes, you would run it once more, and it would just be a quick incremental delta.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the network drive is mounted (NFS or whatever),

```
tail -f -c1000000000000 /your/local/file.dat > /mnt/nfs/drive/file.dat
```

This will start copying your output file to the network drive and keep it synchronized. When your program finishes, you should see the same 200GB file on both local and network fs.  Maybe do a md5sum on both to verify.

Some unix flavors might also support also running `tail` with `--pid={Your pid here}` which will automatically stop tailing when your pid finishes.

Comment: I should note that this will only work if your process writes the file sequentially (usually the case).

Comment: This is a great time-saving idea. As it turns out, though, the file is written randomly, not sequentially. I will add that info to the question. Still, for sequential files, this is a much better way than what I was thinking.

Comment: Dang, random access writing <sound of wrench in machine grinding to stop>. Posting another answer below that came to me after I thought of `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sufficient credit to post a comment.

Admittedly, it does not answer the question. Which is why it should be only taken as a comment. Still, it clearly show some internal view. Which is why I think this comment deserves to be written in this page. Thank you for your time. I am not affiliated in any way with [the site](https://www.baeldung.com).

I find [open-file-handle-after-move-delete](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/open-file-handle-after-move-delete), which is from mid 2021, a well explanation of what happens here. In my opinion, it is much more clear then the [duplicate](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-move-an-open-file-between-filesystems-without-breaking-the-open-file-descriptors-to-it-e-g-to-allow-an-in-use-external-drive-to-be-removed-safely-by-caching-the-relevant-file-locally), stated at a comment by [milahu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/295986/milahu) at May 3 at 13:55.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421428)